# Alfresco SSO with CAS and Apache

Tags: apache, single-sign-on, alfresco, cas

I'm trying to integrate CAS into Alfresco (ver 4.2.0) according to [this guide](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_With_mod_auth_cas). The /alfresco application works fine, but /share doesn't log in. When the org.alfresco.web.site.EditionInterceptor tries to get the license information through the new remote endpoint it gets rerouted to the cas login page (the app is already logged in , and the CAS cookie is in the request). This causes an error, since it expects a JSON response. Could this be coused by the Apache configuration? Or maybe something is wrong with the endpoint?

Comment: Are you sure you followed that correctly? Only the Apache config on that page shows it avoiding CAS for things like the services that Share and Alfresco use to talk to each other, so you really shouldn't be seeing the behaviour you report...

Comment: I guess I should have attached my config files, but it seems to be a little too much for a question on this site. The main differences in my config are that I'm using mod_proxy_ajp instead of mod_jk (although I tried that as well) and I have a proper SSL certificate for apache, so I don't configure the keystore in alfresco.

Comment: If you try hitting some of the alfresco resources that the config marks as not going to CAS, do you correctly get to see them?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to get the css or js files without logging in for example.

Answer (score 0):

Share do the authentication through Alfresco, and make the calls via https, you have to make alfresco and CAS available to share via **https**.
This [article](http://www.ixxus.com/blog/2011/08/configuring-alfresco-sso-cas-and-securing-tomcat) can be a good help.